# Possible to REMOVE rows from current excel, to new?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am wondering if there is a way to extract my troublesome excel rows; that I'm already finding, via the below:

```
            except Exception as exc:
                print (f'Record failed: {record}. {traceback.print_exc()}')
```

I would like to essentially **REMOVE THIS ROW FROM CURRENT EXCEL FILE**, **what** **I am** already **printing** -- then MOVE **into a NEW** EXCEL file *i.e.* /troublesome_rows.csv.

Comment: Are you asking to write the error to a log file? you can do that by direct `print()` to a given file, or open a file instance and write `f'Record failed: {record}. {traceback.print_exc()}'` to that file.

Comment: I want to delete the ROW from current excel, MOVE it to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your code, you want to save `record` to another file:

```
except Exception as exc:
    # exception_ids must be initialized to [] before this loop
    # assumingly record is extracted by df.loc[index]
    exception_ids.append(record.name)
    print (f'Record failed: {record}. {traceback.print_exc()}')
```

After the loop you can do:

```
df.loc[exception_ids].to_excel('exception_records.xlsx')
df.drop(exception_ids, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are catching the exception, you can populate a list of dicts or something that will help you create a dataframe, which you can then save to `troublesome.csv`. Then you have two options: 1) do the same when  not catching the exception and dynamically create those two files, or 2) after you get the troublesome - remove the intersection between original and troublesome.